# Parallelizing identical long-running tasks with Go channels

Tags: go, concurrency

I have written a program in Go to compute the discrete logarithm mod primes (find \$x\$ such that \$h=g^x\mod p\$), and the algorithm I am using can be easily parallelized. Essentially, I am trying to find a value \$a\$ satisfying some slow function, where \$a < 2^{20}\$; rather than check these one by one, I would like to dispatch a number of goroutines to check concurrently.

I haven't written a ton of programs using Go channels before, so I am mostly looking for suggestions about proper usage of channels with goroutines. My actual program is much longer and contains additional math and processing that isn't relevant to my question. If necessary, however, I am happy to post the full code.

Specific things I am wondering about:

- Is there a standard way of determining how many goroutines I should spawn for running such nearly-identical tasks? Specifically, is it best to spawn approx. number of CPUs (4), or is the standard practice to have a goroutine spawned for each value I check? (i.e. move the goroutine inside the main loop, rather than feeding values through a channel; that would be \$\approx 2^{20}\$ calls.) I have heard the adage *"goroutines are not threads"* but I am not sure to what extent that can be (ab)used. I am aware I could performance-tune this parameter, but I'm curious how this question is usually answered when prototyping software.
- I have buffered the `tx` channel so that, if multiple goroutines find a solution at approximately the same time, they don't deadlock waiting for additional reads from `tx` (I only care about one solution, but there may be many). There isn't a way to *block* writes to a channel, is there? Earlier, I was getting program panics after trying to write to a closed channel.
- I have a single `rx` channel, to send data to my goroutines, which I close when I find my first solution. Is this the proper way to do so? I am aware that closing a channel only prevents further writes to it, not future reads. My goal is to have *all* goroutines stop once the *first* one completes.

  - In addition, is this single-sender/multiple-receiver structure acceptable? I'm not aiming for optimal load balancing, of course. Another thing I had tried earlier was to create multiple receivers \$rx_i\$ for each of \$N\$ goroutines, and assign \$a\$ to \$rx_{a \% N}\$. But that presupposes that each goroutine will take equal amounts of time, which isn't true in general.

Pseudocode:

```
package main

import (
    ...
)

func process_equation(rx <- chan *big.Int, tx chan *big.Int) int {
    for a := range rx {
        v := very_slow_function_call(a) // returns bool
        
        if v {
            // found it!
            tx <- fast_function_call(a) // returns big.Int
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    NUM_GOROUTINES := 4

    rx := make(chan *big.Int)
    tx := make(chan *big.Int, NUM_GOROUTINES)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(NUM_GOROUTINES)

    for i := 0; i < NUM_GOROUTINES; i++ {
        go func() {
            process_equation(rx, tx)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }

    a := big.NewInt(0)
    one := big.NewInt(1)
    solution := new(big.Int)
    done := false

    // nonblocking read of `tx`; increment `a` and send otherwise
    for !done {
        select {
        case solution = <-tx:
            close(rx)
            done = true
        default:
            // increment
            a.Add(a, one)
            rx <- new(big.Int).Set(a)
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("a =", solution)

    wg.Wait() // wait for other goroutines to exit

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'd remove the `Pseudocode:` part from your question because this looks like valid code in Go (even though there are parts omitted). [Asking for reviews on pseudocode is off-topic](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652), so people might misunderstand.

Comment: ok. at that point this may be more on-topic at SE.